# Sharing business logic - Web App and Scheduled tasks

Tags: business-logic

Is that okay to share the business logic between a web application and scheduled tasks.
Or should the business logic of the scheduled tasks be separated.
Currently some of the methods of the business logic layer are used only by the scheduled tasks. This seems a little dirty to me taking in consideration the SoC principle. Waiting for answers.

Comment: Is this a duplicate? Can you please provide an answer even if the question is simple or provide some link or something? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Keeping all your business logic consolidated in one place is usually the better option, when other requirements don't make the choice for you. One way to do this is to make scheduled tasks simply call a web hosted method, which it sounds like you are doing. This also comes with the benefit of giving you flexibility to change how scheduled tasks are triggered, or if some tasks may need to be ran on demand in the future.

What uses your business logic isn't really something you need to really be concerned with, apart from unauthorized use. Your business logic layer should only be concerned what your business logic is, not who is consuming any particular piece of it. you seems to be getting a little too into implementation details with separation of concerns.